# php ‘apache_note’ function whilst SUPHP is active

Tags: php, apache, file-permissions, suphp

I am using maxminds geoip apache mod extention. It requires the php function 'apache_note'. However while suphp is active I am unable to access the function.

Ideally I would like to use suphp as I understand it offers security benefits.

Is it possible to use apache_note while also using suphp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's Apache functions are "[only available when running PHP as an Apache module](http://us.php.net/manual/en/intro.apache.php)," according to the docs.  [suPHP](http://www.suphp.org/Home.html) operates very differently from mod_php, so it's very unlikely that you could get it working.

As you're using MaxMind's GeoIP service, have you looked at their [pure-PHP library on PEAR](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_GeoIP/), or the [C implementation on PECL?](http://pecl.php.net/package/geoip)

Comment: What is the advantages/disadvantages between the pear and pecl solutions? Thanks

Comment: @Pablo, with the PEAR solution, you can just drop the library in to your codebase and access it directly, without needing to install it on the server or change the server configuration.  With the PECL package, you'd need to have access to a compiler, and change the server's PHP configuration.  They claim that the PECL package operates faster, and may be right.